# Are there any mail services that don't store encryption keys?

Tags: encryption, email, web-service, disclosure, government

According to this article => http://www.howtogeek.com/166507/why-most-web-services-dont-use-end-to-end-encryption/
Gmail doesn't store the encryption key.
But Gmail reads whole of users' email for advertisement or other purpose like government! (Based on Mr.Snowden disclosure)

> The idea of “end-to-end encryption” — you could also refer to it as
>   “local encryption and decryption” — is different. With end-to-end
>   encryption, the data is decrypted only at the end points. In other
>   words, **an email sent with end-to-end encryption would be encrypted at
>   the source, unreadable to service providers like Gmail in transit, and
>   then decrypted at its endpoint. Crucially, the email would only be
>   decrypted for the end user on their computer and would remain in
>   encrypted, unreadable form to an email service like Gmail, which
>   wouldn’t have the keys available to decrypt it.** This is much more
>   difficult.

**Is gmail or the other mail services doing this ?
(*Storing encrypted data in the database without storing it's private key*)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an email is encrypted, the private key which can be used to decrypt it must be *somewhere*. If the provider does not have it, then *you*, as a user, must store it on your machine. Furthermore, the decryption must then necessarily occur on your own machine. This will not work well (or at all) with a Webmail: Javascript code is ill-suited for such crypto jobs.

If you want to do end-to-end encryption, then you must:

- user a mail *application* which includes the necessary cryptography;
- convince the people who send you emails to themselves use a compatible application.

Indeed, if the mail is encrypted, then it was encrypted somewhere, using your public key.

This points to [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/) along with the plugins which embed GnuPG in an existing mailer application (e.g. [that one](http://www.gpg4win.org/)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
So all of the mail services (even **Google**, **Lavabit** & etc.) encrypt the data before storing them, but they also store the private keys (That's why they have access to their user's data).
Yes?

Comment: It is unknown whether the mail services apply any encryption for storage. You cannot check for it as a client. They use encryption _in transit_ when you read the email (that's what the HTTPS is about), but for storage, that's a complete unknown. _IF_ they encrypt then they also decrypt upon reading, and they have all the relevant keys for that.

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird with the GnuPG plug-in Enigmail is another option for traditional email. For webmail, one can just copy/paste to a stand-alone GnuPG app. It's tedious and somewhat error-prone, but it works. Also, I know of one provider, Countermail, that uses a Java browser plug-in to encrypt messages locally before sending. But Java browser plug-ins are notoriously insecure.

All of these approaches only protect message bodies stored by service providers. Message headers (e.g., "Date", "To", "From" and "Subject") may be encrypted in transit, by SSL/TLS for email or HTTPS for webmail. But they can't be end-to-end encrypted, because they're needed for message routing.

Providers only need users' public keys for encryption. They could encrypt complete messages, sent or received. And then users could decrypt locally in a web plugin, without disclosing their private keys. But I suspect that there's something unworkable about that, because Countermail etc aren't doing it. Also, message headers wouldn't be protected for recipients using insecure providers.